# Implementing json:api in micronaut

Tags: java, json-api, micronaut

I would like to be able to implement json:api in micronaut. I found very few libraries to use with in java. I tried using json-api-converter. However, it proved to be inefficient in performance (as I had to serialize and deserialze about 3 -4 times per request). Is there any other way to implement it?

Comment: What do you mean by "implement json:api in micronaut"?  Do you mean you want REST responses out of a Micronaut service to be jsonapi compliant?

Comment: Yes I want the responses to be of the following format. 

https://jsonapi.org/format/